# Regarding Svoloch

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, call-of-duty-world-at-war

In *Call of Duty: World at War*, during the Vendetta mission, you and Reznov encounter a sniper who Reznov calls Svoloch. In the sequel, *Call of Duty: Black Ops*, during the Vorkuta mission, Mason and Reznov encounter yet another Svoloch, who Mason punches in the face.

Are they the same person? If yes, how did he survive a sniper shot from Dimitri?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not the same person.
"Svoloch/Сволочь" in russian means "Bastard".
The one in World at War was just some sniper, which was shot and killed in mid of Vendetta mission.
The one in Black ops 1, Vorkuta (Gulag), was just some Prison Guard, which Reznov called "Svoloch", Bastard.

The Sniper in Vendetta was German, and the Prison Guard in Vorkuta was Russian and those two events were ~21 years apart from each other.

Comment: And Resnov hadn't aged a day...